# Returning promise inside mongo db document schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, es6-promise

I have following problem: cannot read property 'then' of undefined.
Here is my code:

```
commentSchema.methods.saveIfMovieExist = function () {
const Comment = this;
Movie.findOne({imdbID: Comment.imdbID}).then(movie => {
    if (!movie)
        return Promise.reject();

    return Comment.save();
}, err => {
    return Promise.reject();
}); };
```

And then I have this request:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
const comment = new Comment({
    imdbID: req.body.imdbID,
    text: req.body.text
});

comment.saveIfMovieExist(comment).then(doc => {
    res.send(doc);
}, err => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
});
});
```

I would like to check if movie with imdbID exist and if so insert comment to db. I am missing sth in chaining Promises but can not figure out what. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

you are not returning the find function so first return that, after that you can return promise from it.

```
commentSchema.methods.saveIfMovieExist = function () {
    const Comment = this;
    return Movie.findOne({imdbID: Comment.imdbID}).then(movie => {
        if (!movie)
            return Promise.reject();

        return Comment.save();
    })
};
```